# save nested document on server using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to save model on server.Data I am trying to POST data like

```
 {
      'workingWeek' : 'sat',
        'workingOff' : [
            'sun',
            'mon'
        ],
        'AvailableTimeailableTime': [
            {   
                'day' : 'sat',
                'from' : '12,',
                'too' : '12,',
                'timestamp' : ''
            }
        ]
    }
```

And It posted successfully using postman. When I tried to POST using Backbone. It gives me error bad request. My javascript code is:-

```
 var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url:'http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/availability',
      toJSON: function() {  
     }
    });


    var user=new UserModel({
      'workingWeek' : 'sat',
        'workingOff' : [
            'sun',
            'mon'
        ],
        'AvailableTimeailableTime': [
            {   
                'day' : 'sat',
                'from' : '12,',
                'too' : '12,',
                'timestamp' : ''
            }
        ]
    });

    console.log(user);
    user.save();
```

Header from chrom debugger is:-

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=763119F314E1485DCC8B838F4539BA78
Host:192.168.1.3:8080
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/31.0.1650.63 Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:file://
Connection:close
Content-Length:69
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 17 Feb 2014 13:19:40 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I am new to backbone. What I am missing?

Comment: Why do you have this in the Model? toJSON: function() {}, I believe that it is causing the wrong request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your request headers on model save: `Content-Length:0`, what is absolutely right since you override default `.toJSON` backbone model method. And your version of this method returns void.
Remove this method and try again please.